# axios is not working in react project but fetch working fine

Tags: reactjs, axios

axios code:

```
import Axios from "axios";

export const getBlogPosts = async (setter) => {
  try {
    const res = await Axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`);
    if (res.status === 200 && res?.data) {
      setter(res?.data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

this is my app code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getBlogPosts } from "./_helper";
export function TestCustomerCreate() {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    getBlogPosts(setGridData);
  }, []);
  console.log(gridData);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is test create form</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

error msg: Request failed with status code 404
but when i'm using fetch its working fine (i'm using "axios": "0.19.2" with Metronic theme react (7.0.8)

Comment: I tried your code. I'm using ```"axios": "^0.24.0",``` and the code runs fine. Try updating the version of axios. may be that will fix the issue

Comment: There is no error in the code. it's working fine. I run my device and it's working fine with "axios": "0.19.2".

Comment: @AnkitSaxena code is also runs fine in "axios": "0.19.2" too.

Comment: same here. It working fine on other projects. but i've tried with upgrade version of axios but still get 404 error. Don't know why :(

Comment: @Mohiuddin can you create a sample codesandbox with the code that you're using? Seems like the issue is not with axios but something else

Comment: I think the reason is in Metronic theme react. in default settings axios not work. we need to set up that. I went through there docs and put an answer.

Comment: Try `axios.get` without the capital letter and in the import too

Comment: sorry guys, i've found the solutions. It's about mock axios. I've removed it and now it's working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this is in **Metronic use axios-mock-adapter** for demo purpose, it intercepts axios requests and redirects to mocked handlers. [Mock Back-end](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=react-mock-back-end)

To use real REST APIs need to do 2 things.

1. remove mock initialization. For that remove mock initialization in
   the **src/index.js or src/main.js** file.
2. Remove API initialization from the **src/index or src/main.js**

   ```
   // Remove this to disable mock API
   MockService.init();

   // API service init
   ApiService.init();
   ```

Comment: It didn't help. I didn't find any MockService.init(); in the index.js :(

Comment: @Mohiuddin Don't you have an index.js or main.js file (provided by Metronic) in the initial Metronic theme you used?

Comment: sorry guys, i've found the solutions. It's about mock axios. I've removed it and now it's working fine :)

Comment: @Mohiuddin glad to hear. How did you remove it? with what I pointed out or else? if so put an answer showing how you did that then it might help for others.